# Is there any way to append an argument in ProcessInfo in willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method through a tweak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

We would like to append an argument in ProcessInfo before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method on any app but we don't know if is feasible and what class we should hook. Thanks!

Comment: In the title you ask for injecting code but in the description you what to add an extra argument to ProcessInfo, can you please update you question to be more consistent and clear.

Comment: Edited title to be more consistent and clear as per Christos Koninis request.